# Delphi 7 using a .DLL that is created by VB.net

Tags: vb.net, delphi, dll

I am using Delphi 7 to try to use a .DLL created by VB.net.  When I run TDUMP.EXE on the .DLL, it reports no exported data available.  The VB.Net .DLL uses "RaiseEvent" to return data.

Any help would be useful.

**-- Response to @Cipi --**

OK....I got the .tlb created as instructed.  This is all that is in it:

```
// *********************************************************************//
// GUIDS declared in the TypeLibrary. Following prefixes are used:        
//   Type Libraries     : LIBID_xxxx                                      
//   CoClasses          : CLASS_xxxx                                      
//   DISPInterfaces     : DIID_xxxx                                       
//   Non-DISP interfaces: IID_xxxx                                        
// *********************************************************************//
const
  // TypeLibrary Major and minor versions
  FetcherMajorVersion = 1;
  FetcherMinorVersion = 0;

  LIBID_Fetcher: TGUID = '{2E3B99DB-019A-4857-A03F-A40D418FF3BC}';


implementation

uses ComObj;

end.
```

Also....you said to add ComObj and Yourlib_dll (this will be the name of your dll).  in the uses statement.   I can't get it to accept anything .DLL

Comment: Which type of VB.NET DLL? Is it COM Visible?

Comment: Whats the name of your DLL? If it is `SpongeBob.dll` Delphi will generate `SpongeBob_DLL` unit. The idea is to include in`uses` unit generated in `Import Type Library` in Delphi...

Comment: The name of the DLL is Fetcher.dll.  regasm fetcher.dll /tlb:fetcher.tlb creates the fetcher.tlb amd regesters the file. In delphi, Project->Import Type Library -> Add -> (select fetcher (Version 1.0) and click Create Unit produces fetcher_TLB.pas.  I can't find anything like Fetcher_DLL.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to run regasm from visual studio command prompt for example, and make it generate type library for your assembly:

`regasm YourLib.dll /tlb:TypeLib.tlb`

Now you have `TypeLib.lib` in the same directory that `YourLib.dll` is. Copy both to your Delphi project folder (where exe will be built).

Then in Delphi go to: Project->Import Type Library -> Add -> (locate and select TypeLib.lib) -> Create unit

In uses add "ComObj" and "YourLib_DLL" (this will be the name of your dll).

And then you can use all the classes that are inside the DLL as you could in VB only now if the class was named Point in VB, now it will be called TPoint...